# real solution of $y''=-4yy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Number of real solution of $y''=-4yy'$

what i try

$$\frac{y''}{y}=-4y\Longrightarrow \int \frac{y''}{y}dy = -4\int ydy$$

$$\ln(y')=-2y^2+\ln(c)\Longrightarrow \ln\bigg(\frac{y'}{c}\bigg)=-2y^2$$

$$\frac{y'}{c}=e^{-2y^2}\Longrightarrow y'=ce^{-2y^2}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: The very first equality is already wrong: $\;y''=-4yy'\implies \frac{y''}{y'}=-4y\ldots\;$

Comment: ... and, assuming $x$ is the independent variable, you integrated on the LHS with respect to $x$, while you integrated on the RHS with respect to $y$.

Comment: @DonAntonio The separation of $y'$ is right, but it is a typo on the LHS.

Comment: Why the downvote ? OP has posted his/her attempt ? +1 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got
$$\int y''(x)dx=y'(x)\qquad \qquad \int -4yy' dx=-2\int \frac{d}{dx}(y^2) dx=-2y^2 +C$$
thus
$$y'(x)=-2y^2+C$$

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking of $\;y\;$ a function of some variable $\;x\;$ , let

$$v:=y'\implies y''=v'=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}v\implies$$

$$v\frac{dv}{dy}=-4yv\implies\int dv=-4\int y\,dy\implies v=-2y^2+C\implies\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''=-4yy'$$
You have derivatives on both sides, just integrate:
$$y''=-2 (y^2)'$$
$$y'=-2y^2+C$$